# Convert String to Dictionary Location in Python

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I'm trying to figure out if there's a prebuilt way of converting a string to a dictionary location. I think sample code will be the easiest to explain what I'm trying to do.

```
def main(locate_user_id):
    response = {
        "users": [{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Joe"
        }, {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Bob"
        }]
    }
    print(response)
    print (locate_user_id)
    print (response[locate_user_id])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main("users[1]['id']")
```

The output of this is currently:

```
{'users': [{'id': 1, 'name': 'Joe'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'Bob'}]}
users[1]['id']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_dict.py", line 17, in <module>
    main("users[1]['id']")
  File "test_dict.py", line 14, in main
    print (response[locate_user_id])
KeyError: "users[1]['id']"
```

And I'm looking for a solution that would output this instead:

```
{'users': [{'id': 1, 'name': 'Joe'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'Bob'}]}
users[1]['id']
2 // the id of the user referenced above
```

Comment: You should consider redesigning your code. This is bad design.

Comment: There are some really atrocious answers here. Don't use `eval` and rather redesign the code in a way that allows you to access the data by passing an int.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval{PUT YOUR LIST HERE}
```

Comment: That's not valid Python syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do the trick. A little dirty but it works!

```
def main(locate_user_id):
    response = {
        "users": [{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Joe"
        }, {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Bob"
        }]
    }
    print(response)
    print(locate_user_id)

    keys = locate_user_id.replace(']','').split('[')
    keys[0] = '"' + keys[0] + '"'
    eval_str = '[' + ']['.join(keys) + ']'

    print(eval(str(response) + eval_str))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main("users[1]['id']")
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using `eval`, and with a slight modification of your input, you can achieve what you want using `str.format` which is able to evaluate subscript access without having to use the evil `eval`:

```
def main(locate_user_id):
    response = {
        "users": [{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Joe"
        }, {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Bob"
        }]
    }

    print(("{"+locate_user_id+"}").format(response))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main("[users][1][id]")  # instead of "users[1]['id']"
```

result: `2`

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to restructure the code. The function just takes the response and an index now and prints the corresponding element of the users list.

```
response = {
    "users": [
        {"id": 1, "name": "Joe"},
        {"id": 2, "name": "Bob"}
        ]
    }

def locate_user_id(response, user_id):
    print(response["users"][user_id]["id"])

locate_user_id(response, 1)
```

If you actually want to get the user with the passed id number, you can iterate over the users list:

```
def locate_user_id(response, user_id):
    for user in response["users"]:
        if user["id"] == user_id:
            print(user)
```

Also, if you're able to reorganize the data, then you could try something like this:

```
response = {
    "users": {
        1: "Joe",
        2: "Bob",
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

A string is a string. You need the Python interpreter to be able to understand Python syntax. To invoke the interpreter inside the scope of a script, you can use `eval`.

You need slight modifications to your script for `eval` to work the way you want to:

```
def main(locate_user_id):
    response = {
        "users": [{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Joe"
        }, {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Bob"
        }]
    }
    print(eval('response' + locate_user_id))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main("['users'][1]['id']")
```

What this is doing is evaluating the string `response['users'][1]['id']` in the scope of function `main`.

Whatever the use case, using `eval` is NOT recommended for many reasons you can Google. I would try and refactor your code so as to not necessitate the use of `eval`.

Comment: The OP is asking the wrong question (without realizing it), and that's the one you've answered. What he/she really wants is to understand how to to retrieve data from a nested data structure; in this case, how to search a list for an element which contains the right userId property

Comment: No...the fact that OP has nested access notation in his example code means he is aware.